# start dhcpcd on specific interfaces only explicitly

Tags: network-interface, dhcp

On my machine I have multiple interfaces which often have a dhcp server running. I now want to react differently on various 'setups':

- when there is wifi, use wifi
- when there is ethernet, use ethernet (I have an extra profile there, too)
- when there is both, use one of them (or both, or whatever.. just work)
- when interface `usb0` or `usb1` occur, only enable dhcp on them when someone issues `dhcpcd <interface>`

My current `dhcpcd.conf` looks like

```
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
#clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private


interface eth0
arping 192.168.1.77

profile 192.168.1.77
static ip_address=192.168.1.65
static routers=192.168.1.77
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.77


interface usb0
nogateway

interface usb1
nogateway
```

The wifi/ethernet part seems to work, though I haven't tested it thoroughly. But I don't know, how to set up my usb interfaces to only respond to DHCP on command. The `nogateway` is just there to prevent usb interfaces to screw up my default routes ATM.

How do I need to configure `dhcpcd`?

**Edit 1:**
I am on a Gentoo system with no more network configuration except my `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `allowinterfaces` and/or `denyinterfaces` setting in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.
From `man dhcpcd.conf`

```
 allowinterfaces pattern
         When discovering interfaces, the interface name must match
         pattern which is a space or comma separated list of patterns
         passed to fnmatch(3).  If the same interface is matched in
         denyinterfaces then it is still denied.

 denyinterfaces pattern
         When discovering interfaces, the interface name must not match
         pattern which is a space or comma separated list of patterns
         passed to fnmatch(3).
```

Also possible, although IMO less desirable in production, with args to dhcpcd, `[-Z, --denyinterfaces pattern]`, `[-z, --allowinterfaces pattern]`.

Comment: My apologies for answering ancient question. I could not find its answered duplicate.